# OpenAi Gym Installation - python version mismatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, openai-gym

I am trying to install openai gym on a fresh Ubuntu 16VM. I'm following the documentation to install the Atari package, but I keep running into problems:

When I run 
    ipython > v2.7.12

```
>import gym
>gym.make('SpaceInvaders-v0')
```

I get :

```
....
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

It seems to run python3 code, however, during the installation I used the default settings. When I run

```
python3 > 3.5.2
> import gym
ImportError: No module named 'gym'
```

What am I doing wrong? I installed gym into the user environment with `pip --user` parameters.

Solution:
Simple fix to use `pip3` which is unfortunately not mentioned in the Readme :(

Comment: Perhaps try installing to `pip3 --user` instead of `pip --user`?

Comment: Sure! :D I'll try

Comment: That was it, thank you!

Comment: Ok great to hear that it solved your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install to a Python3 environment use the following command

`pip3 --user`

For debugging between Python2 and Python3 `pip` environments the following commands are often useful:

`pip3 --version`

`pip --version`

It prints out the corresponding Python environment that it is attached to